# Retrofit Not building url as expected Android

Tags: android, url, retrofit

In this got library im trying to implement an simple url like this.....http://www.retrofitHorrible.com/somePath/someAnother/?searchCriteria[tooHorrible] and etc.Issue is that Retrofit i guess did not handle this case as if i try like this

```
 @GET("somePath/someAnother/")
    Call<ProductModel> getProductsList(@Query("searchCriteria") String appendedUrl);
```

this part will give me URL like this

`?searchCriteria=searchCriteria[tooHorrible]`...What is this url even?
Anyway if i try with

```
@Path(value="searchCriteria" encoded=false)
```

it will give me url like `%3FsearchCriteria[tooHorrible]` where the %3F is the got ? mark which i am trying to implement MORE THEN MONTH and i tried every possible solution of this library.
Anyway nothing works and what i want is to build an simple damn url like this

```
?searchCriteria[tooHorrible] is this too much for asking for this library?
```

How in world even i can build such URL? because all above ones are incorrect and will not work!

Comment: What is `?searchCriteria[tooHorrible]`? A query is `?key=value` not [ and ]

Comment: it is an url to by which i am accessing some list,it is working this way  with any request makers with any in whole world applications which makes simple request,with simple browser,but wow not with rertofit and it should be built that way

Comment: Which part of your url is changing? `searchCriteria` or `tooHorrible`?

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution for your problem is adding a query parameter...
Try the below link to find how to query in url.

https://futurestud.io/blog/retrofit-multiple-query-parameters-of-same-name

Comment: please read more attentive.....as i said that i have tried that and it gives me not ?searchCriteria but ?searchCriteria=searchCriteria which is incorrect url

Comment: then i think you should change the value of String appendUrl that you are passing...Just send only the tooHorrible part

Comment: In the given code....@GET("somePath/someAnother/").....Remove the slash at the end....and the new code looks like this... @GET("somePath/someAnother")

Answer (score 0):

It is not Retrofit's fault. It is how apache interprets the requests.

You are making two mistakes:
1: Pass value for your query parameter otherwise apache won't get it. Check API documentation properly.
2: If however, you want to use URL without query parameter value ReWrite URL rules by creating a .htaccess file on your server something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)searchCriteria[tooHorrible]$
RewriteRule ^api/?$ xyz.php?searchCriteria=tooHorrible[NC,L]
```

I guess this is something what you want.
Check [this](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase) link for more info on rewrite rules.Check [this](https://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/Regexe.html#zz-2.4) link for information on Regular Expressions.[Good Article](http://statichtml.com/2010/mod-rewrite-baseon-on-query-string.htm) on Rewrite.

Please explain your URL. otherwise no one would be able to help. Hope this helps :)
l